# Issue accessing data for Rails Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

The issue started after I added the `rental_application_personal_details` and tried to access to `first_name` from the table.

Controller:

```
def create
  unless @rental_application.submittable?
    redirect_to @rental_application, notice: "You can't submit the rental application unless you complete it!"
    return
  end

  if @rental_application.submitted!
    RentalApplicationMailer.sales_agent_message(@rental_application, @rental_application_personal_details, @agent).deliver_now
    if @rental_application.payment_request.authorized
    CapturePaymentJob.perform_later(@rental_application.payment_request)
    else
      @rental_application.payment_request.void!
    end

    redirect_to @rental_application, notice: 'Your application was submitted! :)'
  else
    redirect_to @rental_application, notice: 'We were unable to submit your application.'
  end
end
```

Rental Application Mailer:

```
def sales_agent_message(rental_application, rental_application_personal_details, agent)
  @rental_application = rental_application
  @rental_application_personal_details = rental_application_personal_details
  @agent = agent
  @sales_agent = @rental_application.sales_agent.email
  mail(:to => @sales_agent, :subject => "New Rental Application Recieved!")
end
```

Sales Agent Message:

Hiya!

<%= @rental_application_personal_details.first_name %> has sent you a rental application! %>

View it <%= link_to 'HERE!', matrix_rental_applications_url %>

Error:

[image]

Comment: @rental_application_personal_details   is nil.. check what is coming in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@rental_application_personal_details` seems to never be set anywhere. In your `create` method, you're using it but you never gave it a value in the first place. Thus, it's nil. `nil.first_name` is the error you currently have.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as

```
if @rental_application.submitted! && @rental_application_personal_details.present?

//code to send the mail

end
```